# IE 11 jumps to embedded Google map after page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer-11

We have an embedded Google map on a site. It works like a charm in every browser incl. IE<=10.

On IE11, however, under unspecific circumstances, the browser jumps (scrolls) after firing the load event to the Google map, which happens to be somewhat below the "fold". ("Unspecific circumstances": Especially the homepage does not exhibit this peculiar problem, but sub-pages and pages on subdomains do reliably, although the embedding code is identical.)

Searching the web brings [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/qpE6_1t88Rw) in the Google product forum, that, if nothing else, proves that it's not an exclusive problem of our site.

I am searching for an idea how to debug this and finding the root cause for the jump. Perhaps anyone has already found this problem, or there is a (new) config option for embedded maps, that controls this behavior?

Comment: Hmm ... it might be interesting to see what `document.querySelector("*:focus")` returns from the developer console when it happens.

Comment: Good idea, but it’s `null` (on the freshly loaded page). Also I found a page, where the jump can be reproduced reliably, even after a browser restart. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have a "root cause for the jump" I do have a solution to avoid this. As you can see on this [site I developed](http://souldoutfesival.com), I've implemented Lazy Loading through the use of the WordPress plugin BJ Lazy Load. As the google map iframe doesn't appear in the DOM till you scroll to that region, the "focus" issue never occurs. For non-WP sites, you can use [VVO's jquery plugin](https://github.com/vvo/lazyload).

Comment: That's a neat idea, thanks! I'll check back with my client, if they would want that implemented.

Comment: Good luck. Lazy loading is also just good sense for pages that have a lot of DOM elements. This simple trick slashed the time for page load by 60%.

Comment: OK, we are going to deploy exactly this solution. Thanks for the answer!